# Hashing chunks of big file

Tags: bash, hash

I have a big audio file (2 hours) `foo.mp3`. I want to enable a third party P to verify the date of its creation. However P shall only be able to view (hear) small certain parts of `foo.mp3`. On the date of the creation it is unclear which parts will be provided to P.

So my plan is to split `foo.mp3` into small chunks, hash these chunks and publish the hashes somewhere on the net for later verification.

How would a bash script look like that splits `foo.mp3` and creates hashes?

Comment: **What have you tried so far**? Splitting an audio file is possible with various tools. Are you looking for a tool recommendation, or help with your own code?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to split the file into chunks. Just publish the SHA256 of the whole file now and when the other party gets access to the file they will be able to see that it has the same SHA256 sum that you published earlier. (I'd recommend using at least SHA256 as the hash algorithm.)

Now if you still decide you have to do it like this for some reason, I suggest using `split`(1) and then running `sha256sum`:

```
mkdir split
split -b8192 foo split/
sha256sum split/*
```

This creates splits of the file into 8KB chunks in the `split/` directory and prints the SHA256 hashes.

Comment: I clarified my question. The chunks have to be complete audio files.

Comment: All right... What do you use to stream your file? You could give out the hashes for the raw chunks or for the decoded PCM, but if your streaming software does any re-encoding at all, the hashes will all end up completely different.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Splitting the file into several chunks

```
mp3splt -a -t 0.01 -o foo-@n -d outputDir foo.mp3
```

## 2. Create hashes

```
sha256sum outputDir/* > hashes.sha
```

## 3. Document results on the web

The outcome of a published file with sha256 hashes and/or sha256 hashes of big sha256 hashfiles could look like this:)

5b2718841d2f610ce264191760383dca309fd5a6f8c745e7466aa6c157e0b279  Files1.sha
0b568a4e802e9bc29740e8904c09f361c844dc4bd11d8855a188e81672f453ba  Files2.sha
d8fec62a53228cf372ce81f4e3fd220b2df7bb5d5f8b144c8ffa4e41a4aeaad4  Camera.zip
ac0e59caa3f91f49824540fa452e285b9e47843f24dda309955a5287db4c89b5  Camerasmall.zip
e1f9b37f15eed99a8814f066021e6d370fd4e346b2779fc6494ee685b9e02467  SoundsSmall.zip
d054a2ac8adf069c2051659c68e38a7b6e26172afb2a6c377f7d067c666f9f6e  Sounds.zip